# Any way to see mail sent by other user through shared address?

Tags: gmail

My wife and I have a "shared" email address, like `thesmiths@example.com` which we both use from Gmail when we both want to get replies or for signing up for certain websites.

When an email is received at that address, it gets forwarded to both of our personal Gmail accounts.

The problem is that when either one of us "sends as" that address, the other does not see the sent message. So we have to cc or bcc each other (and she usually forgets.)

Is there any automagic way to have those sent emails appear in *both* of our Gmail accounts?

I've tried filters but I don't think they work on outgoing messages. Basically we want a filter that would automatically forward emails from that address to the other person.

I know this can be done with standalone mail clients, but neither of us uses those. I want this to work by using Gmail webmail interface exclusively.